# SQL select with conditions on previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

How to write such select:

```
SELECT filename, username, date_time, field1, field2... FROM... JOIN... WHERE...
UNLESS user_downloaded_this_file_today_already
```

I would like to ignore files downloaded by the same user on the same day. Data example:

```
12 | file1.jpg | barney | 2012-03-15 12:50:10 | ...
13 | file1.jpg | roger  | 2012-03-15 13:50:10 | ...
14 | file2.jpg | barney | 2012-03-15 14:50:10 | ...
15 | file1.jpg | barney | 2012-03-15 15:50:10 | ...
```

How do I write a SELECT that would ignore 4th line? Same filename, same user, day difference < 1. Is this actually possible?

Comment: "Previous" has no meaning unless there is ordering. Do you order by dates?

Comment: Edited it a bit. It's like "previously this day"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`SELECT DISTINCT`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/) (assuming you don't need the numeric column since it's not in your select):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  FileName,
                 UserName,
                 Date_Time
FROM             [YourTable]
```

If your `Date_Time` column contains times and not just `00:00:00`, you'll need to strip out the time for `DISTINCT` to work properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  FileName,
                 UserName,
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, Date_Time))) AS Date_Time
FROM             [YourTable]
```

Here's [an example of the date stripping in action](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64104/strip-time).

Comment: @Phil, it's fixed - I copied and pasted a bit to quick. Here's an example of the stripping - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64104/strip-time

Comment: OP also needs to select the `field1, field2...` (from the "first" row in the day), so DISTINCT won't work.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, I think that's an assumption. Nothing in the OP says that he needs those values from the "first" row. In addition, we have no idea what data is in `field1` or `field2`. How do you know it would break the `DISTINCT` selection?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic actually field1, field2 are image data, so they will be the same.

Comment: How could I not see that I can use DISTINCT here..? Is there a away to use BOTH distinct with day-difference and also display time (hh:mm)?

Comment: @yosh, You could use `MIN()` or `MAX()` to grad the first or last instance of the download `date_time` column

Comment: @Downvoter, since the OP indicates in his comment that this is the solution they are looking for, do you mind removing the downvote?

Comment: Used this solution after all, simply stripped the time off dates since there was no time required.

Answer (score 4):

In order to allow duplicates in the day, I think the following would suffice:

```
select filename, username, date_time, field1, field2
  from yourtable t
 where not exists (
    select 1 
      from yourtable
     where t.filename = filename
       and t.username = username
       and trunc(t.date_time) = trunc(date_time)
       and t.date_time > date_time)
 order by t.date_time
```

this will return the first requests for each file/user combination per day.

Comment: I'll give it a shot but I've quite a big query with few tables and multiple left joins :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT filename, username, date_time, field1, field2
FROM (
  SELECT filename, username, date_time, field1, field2,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY username,filename, CONVERT(date,date_time)) AS RN,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY username,filename, CONVERT(date,date_time)) AS R

  FROM [table]
) A
WHERE A.RN = A.R
```